# Why is the need of Protected constructor in Abstract class in java

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, protected

While reviewing the java code, I have seen that the constructor of an abstract class is made protected.

```
public abstract class A {
   protected A() {

   }
}
```

What

> Abstract means to me is that you can't create the instance of this
>   class and use this class after extending

.

> And protected constructor also ensures that.

What is the point of doing two things, one making constructor protected and second making the class abstract for solving the same purpose.

Comment: A protected constructor can be called by subclasses or by classes in the same package.

Comment: Why _not_ have a protected constructor for your abstract class? Is declaring it `public` preferable in some way, even though it is misleading?

Comment: @SudhirOjha classes in same package?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that reducing the visibility of the constructor in an abstract class (from `public` to `protected`) changes nothing regarding the inability of code to directly instantiate the abstract class.

However, that is not the point. One makes the constructor `protected` just to control scopes, in the same way one makes member properties private.

Here's a modified version of the same class showing that the point is not to prevent instantiation:

```
public abstract class A {
    protected A() {
        this(0);
    }
    private A(int a) {
        // not accessible to anyone but members of A
        // the point is not to prevent instantiation, but to restrict access
    }
}
```

If making the constructor protected were meant to prevent instantiation, then one could argue that instantiation would be possible within the abstract class itself or its subclasses.

Answer (score 5):

Making the constructor `protected` doesn't prevent other classes from the same package or other classes that extend this class from instantiating the class using this constructor. Therefore the `abstract` keyword is required to prevent instantiating.

You can declare the constructor of an `abstract` class as `public`, but you still won't be able to instantiate this class, so it's pointless. On the other hand, a `private` constructor will not be usable by sub-classes of your `abstract` class (only be other constructors of the `abstract` class itself). Hence, any constructor of the `abstract` class that should be available to all sub-classes of the `abstract` class should be `protected`.

Of course, in your particular example there's no need to declare the constructor at all, since it has an empty body and there are no other constructors. This means the compiler will generate a parameter-less constructor with an empty body anyway.